# How to fix amCharts4 formatting when updating hidden chart's data

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

When the I temporarily hide my am4Charts XYChart and update the data, the formatting of the axes and title is messed up. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Call the `reinit()` function on your chart object.